# Upload image with RSpec has unexpected class on controller

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm in trouble with RSpec and `fixture_file_upload` on post request.

Here's the problem: I'm trying to send an image by upload to create a category with image, but when the image arrives, it changes it's class type.

I'm waiting to get in `params[:category][:image]` an `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` but what I receive is `ActionController::Parameters`.

My request example:

```
    context 'when creates a new main category with valid params' do
      let(:category) do
        { category: { name: 'Bolos E bolos',
                      description: 'São bolos sim',
                      locale: 'pt-BR',
                      image: fixture_file_upload('images/test-image.png', 'image/png') } }
      end

      post '/v4/categories' do
        it 'upload image' do
          expect { do_request(category) }.to change { ActiveStorage::Blob.count }.from(0).to(1)
        end
      end
    end
```

what I got:

```
Failure/Error: expect { do_request(category) }.to change { ActiveStorage::Blob.count }.by(1)
       expected `ActiveStorage::Blob.count` to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

How do I send the image as upload and get it on the controller as `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` instead `ActionController::Parameters`

Comment: can you spin up the above in a minimal rails app and post to github?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  [here](https://github.com/gabrielthleal/active-storage-test)

Comment: I suspect the problem lies with rspec_documentation_api and params being approved, but I can't be sure of it. please do let me know if you solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not get your controller spec working, but I managed to get an equivalent request spec working. Having spent 45+ minutes getting no where, I think this is the best I can do. This seems to work. (Just make sure you have an avatar.jpg in the public folder of your rails app.)

```
## spec/requests/user_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Users", type: :request do

  describe "it attaches uploaded files" do
    it 'attaches the uploaded file' do
      file = fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('public', 'avatar.jpg'), 'image/jpg')
      expect {
        post api_users_path, params: { user: {username: "Ben", avatar: file } }
      }.to change(ActiveStorage::Attachment, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: As you said before seems it doesn't work with rspec_api_cocumentation, I don't know why too.
I hope that someone tells us the reason for it one day. 
I just put it out of `resource`, calling a new `RSpec.describe` and doing a new request. 
The only complain is that I don't was able to document it. Btw, Thankyou, BKSpurgeon. You helped a lot!

Comment: I suspect it's the way params has now been implemented - it's no longer a hash,  but an object. Byebug says that the params were received but not implemented with rspec documentation. Perhaps it's worth raising an issue

Comment: I have actually created an issue here: https://github.com/zipmark/rspec_api_documentation/issues/448